# How do we get 25kV at power stations?

Tags: electricity, voltage

Could anyone tell how we get a potential difference of 25000v at [power stations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_station)? Is it due to the number of electrons present or the speed of the turbine or the large induced emf generated by the revolving magnets?To be honest I'm not looking for the steps in producing [AC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_current) voltage as given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electricity_generation).

Comment: They are using transformers, however, for large generators the generator voltage is on the order of 25kV. It has to be, if you want to produce 1000MW of electricity in a large power plant. 1000MW/25,000V=40,000A, which is a large current that requires very thick conductors (I would say several cm in diameter). If the voltage was any lower, even thicker conductors would be required.

Comment: @CuriousOne:I would like to know what's the main _factor_ behind such a **large** voltage produced at power stations.

Comment: The change in magnetic flux trough the windings of the machine times the turns around the flux. The number of turns is an adjustable engineering parameter. You can use thick wire and get a small voltage and high current or you can use thin wire and get a high voltage and small current. The product of the two will always be the same, i.e. the power generated by the machine. The flux itself is given by the area, i.e. the size of the machine, the magnetic field (approx. 1-1.5T) and the rpms, which are fixed by the line frequency.

Comment: @CuriousOne:Could you explain the term 'line frequency' and how it relates with rpms.

Comment: @justin, CuriousOne has given you all the ingredients.  It's up to you to bake the cake.

Comment: At this point I am actually voting to close because your question belongs, strictly speaking, into engineering. The design details of large power generators are well documented in the engineering literature. We can explain magnetic induction to you, if you like, but how one gets from a wire and a changing magnetic field to a working power generator, that's really not a physics problem.

Answer (score 1):

A power station or generator is not the thing you are asking about here - Your main question is why 25kV is the output.

When designing a power station an engineer tries to get the most power out of the system as possible for a given input of energy, or peak efficiency.

After the generator distribution and use becomes the main concern.  It tends to be the practicalities of distribution and use that determine the high voltages required. Having a high standard voltage enables a few things to happen.

- More than once power station can put power onto the same grid, without fear of massive back flows of energy.
- More than one type of power station can be used in the same network.  Renewable power stations (wave generators, solar panels) are typically harder to turn off like a traditional power station, This makes it hard to balance supply and demand.
- Power stations can be brought online and offline without affecting user experience, but balancing demand.
- When moving electricity across the transmission grid high current generates heat, through resistance, this can be minimised through increasing the voltage. Heat is bad for a number of reasons - Firstly it represents an unwanted energy transfer, it secondly allows wires to deform easier, and thus degrades their working life.
- High voltages can cause problems the voltage must be low enough that air can't conduct the power to earth. (Think lightning between power cables and earth).

Having a standard set of voltages in distribution also allows devices at the consumer's end of things to operate in a predictable environment.

Answer (score 0):

The generators in power stations consist of coils rotation in a magnetic field produced by an electromagnet.  Some of these electromagnets are energised by the generator itself but the larger generator have a smaller generator associated with them to provide the current which passes through the electromagnet.

The induced voltage depends on the magnetic field strength, the area and number of turns on the coils and the speed of revolution of the coils.  Many of the generators in the UK rotate at 3000 rpm which is equivalent to an output frequency of 50 Hz.  Taking account of these factors the output from these generators are typically 10s of kilovolts.

If the output voltage was significantly lower then for a given power output the currents in the coils would have to be higher.  This would require thicker coils to reduce ohmic heating and would increase the size and the cost of the generator.  A higher voltage output which would reduce the current but would require better insulation which again would increase the size and cost.

Comment: :Could you tell how _speed_ of revolution of coils depends on the magnetic field strength?

Comment: It does not.  The speed of revolution depends on how faster the turbine is rotating the shaft of the coil.

Comment: :Oh sorry.I meant to ask how the induced voltage  depends on the _speed_ of revolution of coils?

Comment: The induced voltage is proportional to the speed of revolution.

Comment: :Could you tell by which relation 'induced voltage is proportional to the speed of revolution'?

Comment: Does this link help you? http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/node90.html

Comment: :Oh that's really right.Induced voltage depends upon $\omega$ as given in the [link](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/node90.html).

Comment: :Does all power station of types like nuclear,steam,water etc use the principle of electromagnetic induction?

Comment: I think that in terms of large scale electricity production only the solar photovoltaic panels do not use electromagnetic induction.

Comment: :Yeah that's true.